# Asymptotic upper bound $T(n)=(T(\sqrt{n}))^2$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

The question is to find asymptotic upper bound for recurrence:

$T(n) = (T(\sqrt{n})^2$

$T(n)=n$ for $n\leq 2$

I tried using the guessing the solution method and got $O(n)$.

I am not sure if this is the correct asymptotic upper bound, can someone confirm?

Comment: Is $(T(n))$ a *sequence* (i.e. indexed by $n\in\Bbb N$)? But then $T(\sqrt n)$ is frequently undefined. So, what is $T$? For which $n$'s does your "recurrence" hold?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong: I simply observe that for every n larger than 2, there is a natural number Kn such that $$n^{\frac{1}{2^{K_n}}} \leq 2.$$ This implies $$T(n) = (T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{K_n}}}))^{2^{K_n}}.$$ But $$T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{K_n}}}) = n^{\frac{1}{2^{K_n}}}, $$ and so we actually have T(n) = n.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing $n^* =\{ n | \sqrt{n}\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}\}$ and assuming $T(n^*)\gt 0$ then

$$
\ln\left(T(n^*)\right)=2\ln\left(T(\sqrt{n^*})\right)
$$

or

$$
\ln\left(T(2^{\log_2 n^*})\right)=2\ln\left(T(2^{\frac 12\log_2 n^*})\right)
$$

now calling $z = \log_2 n^*$ we follow with the recurrence

$$
R(z) = 2 R\left(\frac z2\right)
$$

with solution $R(z) = c_0\frac z2 = c_1 z$ and now going backwards

$$
\ln\left(T(n^*)\right) = c_1\log_2 n^*=c_2\ln n^*
$$

and finally

$$
T(n^*) = (n^*)^{c_2}
$$